# Not able store docx,pdf,csv files in GridFs

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I'm have using Php, MongoDb and GridFs to store and retrieve files. It works fine for images, but I want to store files with docx, pdf, csv and etc. extensions. Here is my code:

```
$ext = $this->getFileExt($_FILES["news_attachment"]["name"]);
                switch ($ext) {
                    case 'pdf':
                        $mimeType = 'application/pdf';
                        break;
                    case 'doc':
                        $mimeType = 'application/msword';
                        break;
                    case 'docx':
                        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
                        break;
                    case 'xls':
                        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
                        break;
                    case 'xlsx':
                        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
                        break;
                    case 'ppt':
                        $mimeType = 'application/x-mspowerpoint';
                        break;
                    case 'pptx':
                        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
                        break;
                    case 'csv':
                        $mimeType = 'text/csv';
                        break;
                    case 'txt':
                        $mimeType = 'text/plain';
                        break;
                    default:
                    $mimeType='application/pdf';
                }
                $gridFs = $this->getGridFs();
                $fileData = array(
                    "filename" => microtime(true) . "." . $ext,
                    "contentType" => $mimeType);
                $_id = $gridFs->storeUpload("news_attachment", $fileData);
```

But I get the same error message  `Message: error setting up file:` . I've checked the file size is 78kb, `$fileData` is ok also. So, my question is - What else can caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

Would you not be supplying the same argument when trying to upload:

```
$gridFs->storeUpload($_FILES["news_attachment"]["name"],
```

or possibly

```
$gridFs->storeUpload($_FILES["news_attachment"]["tmp_name"],
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add check for error `if(!empty($_FILES["news_attachment"]) && $_FILES["news_attachment"]["error"] == 0){ save file}`